# Subsetting rows of a dataframe using another dataframe with unequal rows

Tags: r, subset

I have 2 dataframes A and B such that

```
>A
x y z
1 1 1
2 3 5
1 4 6
3 2 5
2 1 3
1 3 5
4 4 5

>B
x
1
3
```

Essentially dataframe B contains values of x that indicate the rows of data I would like to have from dataframe A.  The output I would like to have is a third dataframe C such that

```
>C
x y z
1 1 1
1 4 6
1 3 5
3 2 5
```

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: did you already try something by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I used a for loop to search for matches in A[,'x'] for each element in B[,'x'] and then output the entire row of A that matches.  For a small dataframe, it is fine.  However, I have a dataset that contains 6 million observations and this method takes a substantial amount of time.  Any more efficient way?

Comment: what's the programming language you're using?

Comment: R.  By the way, I found the solution on another thread.  Basically, just use C <- A[A$x %in% B,]

Comment: in future try to define what programming language your question refers to and what have you tried already by yourself in order to solve your problem :) these are helpful info for other peers.